# Convert application/octet-stream;base64, to json String or Simple Text using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mime-types

I am trying to get a json structure using ajax request and put json into a text box, but response return is of type application/octet-stream;base64, so it can't accept as simple text.

```
function loaddata(){
var viewurl = "http://portalvhdskvdvlnrgl9scn.blob.core.windows.net/mbqrbxgghr/view_031ca05f-4e2e-49d6-ac6a-e05308340658.json";
$.ajax({
    url: viewurl,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#view').val(data);   
    }
});
}
```

I am getting response code 200.

Comment: If you save the json string to a file into your localhost and refer that url in your code then this code must work

Comment: @Swarnajith how will I do it, I mean create and read data from file.
**P.S.** Also tell me to how I will delete the file after Reading it.

Comment: if you go to the url which have specified for json retrieval it pops up u to download that, so download it and save it as whatever the name you desire, lets say for example externaldata.json and include it as the url. I checked it this way and it works I can view the data.

Comment: @Swarnajith Sorry for late response. I tried it on firefox it didn't work. I don't want user to download and save file, it should do all the magic behind the scene. I want I click on a button and data comes to text box from url.

Comment: what i told was for u to put it in your server, not the user to download it. include it in your server where your website is hosted(i.e. in your web hosting space in your domain) just like other files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm bumping up against the Same Origin policy when trying to run that code in Chrome.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load.     Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The URL does return a valid JSON response however.